# Counting non-degenerate parallelograms in permutation arrays

Tags: combinatorics

I am interested in finding out more about the function $P(n)$ that counts the number of distinct non-degenerate parallelograms whose vertices are in distinct rows and columns of an $n$ x $n$ array.  Enumerative C++ code with nested loops shows that $P(4)=6$, $P(5)=62$, and $P(6)=362$ and also produced the values of $P(n)$ for $4 \leq n \leq 129$.  This data (or a heuristic argument) shows that $P(n)$ has $n^6$ growth.  If possible, I would like to find a recurrence relation or generating function for $P(n)$. Curve fitting for large $n$ appears to suggest that there is an asymptotic constant $\alpha \approx 0.0514$ such that $P(n)\sim \alpha n^6$.  I would also like to know if $\alpha$ exists and to know its true value if it does exist.

Comment: Could you add an example of that $4 \times 4$ array? I want to confirm that I've got the right idea.

Comment: The 6 non-degenerate parallelograms in a 4 x 4 permutation array have vertices (row,column):

1:  (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,4)
2:  (1,2) (2,1) (3,4) (4,3)
3:  (1,3) (2,1) (3,4) (4,2)
4:  (1,2) (2,4) (3,1) (4,3)
5:  (1,3) (2,4) (3,1) (4,2)
6:  (1,4) (2,2) (3,3) (4,1)


I just found out on Friday, February 5 that a paper I coauthored solving this problem was accepted for publication by an online journal.  I will post a link when the paper appears.

Comment: I coauthored a paper with a solution to this problem.  Please see Theorems 1 and 2 of 

[link to EJC paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v23i1p44)

Comment: That looks like one heck of a self-answer. Go for it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Theorems 1 and 2 in the new paper

http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v23i1p44

that I coauthored solve this problem.

Comment: Why is there a -1 here?  We were stumped on this and eventually figured it out.  The question came well before the paper!!